# How do I build an App IPA without the App Clip Embedded?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-appclips

I am working on an App Clip on an existing App but the App Clip is not ready to ship. However, I need to deploy the App to TestFlight/AppStore for a bug fix.

What is the best way to exclude the App Clip from the App in the interim without removing the App Clip target and code in the XCode project? I just want to build an App IPA without the App Clip so I can submit to TestFlight/AppStore without removing the App Clip target/code from the project.

[image]

Looking at the Build Phases of the project, I figured I need to first remove the App Clip as a Dependency from the App's target. Then there is the "Embed App Clips" Build Phase.  I cannot just remove the AppClip in the Embed App Clips build phase - Archive will create an empty AppClips folder in the App IPA. I have to remove the Embed App Clips from the Build Phases, however if I remove it, there is no obvious way of adding it back, at least I don't see it.

[image]

Currently my only option is to write a Archive Post-action Run Script to remove it from the Archive.

Has anyone ran into this situation before and would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select `New Copy Files Phase`
2. Choose `Destination -> App Clips`
3. Tap `+` button, select `YourClip.app` file
4. (Optional) Rename build phase to `Embed App Clips`